# pandas filter if name appears in column more than n times

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

this is my dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['Joe','Bob','Joe','Joe'],
                  'Col2':[55,25,88,80]})
```

I only want the names of if it appears more than once in 'Col1'

I can do it like this

```
grouped = df.groupby("Col1")
grouped.filter(lambda x: x["Col1"].count()>2)['Col1'].unique()
```

However that is ugly looking code

Is there simpler cleaner way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `value_counts` and `isin`

```
vc = df.Col1.value_counts() > 2
vc = vc[vc]

df.loc[df.Col1.isin(vc.index)]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but looking that will work if I want n to be more than 2  I should have made that clearer  I edited my question

Comment: if you do: print df.loc[df.Col1.isin(vc.index)], it would save you the hassle of png's

Comment: @Merlin I don't mind the png. What do think though?  Text or pic?

Comment: Text is what I do. b/ Im lazy.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a NumPy based solution using [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) -

```
unq,count = np.unique(df.Col1,return_counts=True)
out = unq[count>n]
```

Sample run -

```
In [34]: df
Out[34]: 
  Col1  Col2
0  Joe    55
1  Bob    25
2  Joe    88
3  Joe    80
4  Joe    44
5  Bob    24
6  Joe    45

In [35]: unq,count = np.unique(df.Col1,return_counts=True)

In [36]: unq[count>3] # n = 3
Out[36]: array(['Joe'], dtype=object)
```